# "This app can't run on your PC" after installing Python and trying to check the version on command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

After installing Python on my laptop, I tried to check the version on command prompt and it kept telling me app cannot be open:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Looks like you forgotten to check the tick box set path for the environment variable.